# ng-class issue with condition in angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ng-class

I have two link which is displaying two different images on click of respective link.first behaviour is fine but when again I click on selected link, image is displaying correct but hover is moving to another link. I mean its displaying second link as selected.
here is what I did up to now.

Can someone help what I am doing wrong?

`this.toogleClick` is **true**

```
loadingImg(folder) {
    this.toggleClick = !this.toggleClick;
    this.meta
      .getToken(
        "images",
        this.imgName.ReportJobId,
        (folder == "input" ?
          this.imgName.UniquePhotoName :
          this.imgName.UniquePhotoName
            .replace(".JPG", ".png")
            .replace(".jpg", ".png")),
        folder
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.imgSrc = this.someurl(data);
      }, () => {
        this.imgSrc = "assets/images/image.jpg";
      });
  }

<ul class="result__image--tabslist">
            <li class="result__image--tab left left__tab" (click)="loadImg('output')">
                <span class="result__tab--txt" [ngClass]="toggleClick?'selected':''">
                    Scan
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="result__image--tab left" (click)="loadImg('input')">
                <span class="result__tab--txt" [ngClass]="toggleClick?'':'selected'">
                    Original
                </span>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

`[class.selected]="toggleClick"`

instead of

`[ngClass]="toggleClick?'':'selected'"`

This way the `selected` class is applied only if `toggleClick` is true.

Comment: Hi. style is not changing. both are displaying as selected.

Comment: You put the same class directive on both images. Of course they both have `selected` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
[class]="toggleClick?'selected':''"
```

or,

```
[ngClass]="{'selected': toggleClick}"
```

or,

```
[class.selected]="toggleClick"
```